# Regex to parse square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <url>
        <![CDATA[http://site.ru/uploadImage?returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.ru%2Fdk%3Fcmd%3DgrPostImageUploaded%26amp%3Btkn%3D3089&returnErrorUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.ru%2Fdk%3Fcmd%3DgrPostImageUploaded%26amp%3Btkn%3D3916&flashLoad=on&photoId=]]>
    </url>
    <tokens>
        <token>
            <!CDATA[258xA2Z4KDWBBRo%2FBbZBLZqw%2F1adFyhFOsWKJTidWIgxfIJ8RWZYdpIsOJ3U6RevDsRBR7gKeG2V29evBOFXUaqTg%3D%3D]]>
        </token>
    </tokens>
    <maxImageSize>
        1024
    </maxImageSize>
</data>
```

I try to parse `token><![CDATA[(.*)]]` with code

```
string token = Regex.Match(upload_info, @"CDATA[(.*)]]></token").Groups[1].Value;
```

But token is empty. Why?

Comment: `[]` have a special meaning in regex

Comment: Are you trying to parse XML with regex?

Comment: There are XML parsers out there, and you should use them

Comment: What value do you get in "Groups[0].value"?

Comment: Mostly relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/82682

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[(.*)]` means "one character of the following: `(`, `.`, `*` or `)`".

You probably meant `@"CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]></token"`.

Note the reluctant quantifier `.*?`, or you would match everything from the very first `[CDATA` to the very last `]]</token`.

But you shouldn't be using a regex for parsing XML in the first place, especially not `CDATA` sections. That's what parsers are there for.